# How to get back to main screen / library view in Kindle Modern UI app for Windows 8 using PC with mouse?

Tags: windows-8, kindle, windows-store

I just downloaded the Kindle Modern UI app for Windows 8, from the Windows Store.  I'm using Windows 8 on a regular PC with mouse, i.e. no touchscreen or touchpad capability.

When I launched the Kindle app and logged in to my Amazon account, I could see a list of the Kindle books I had previously purchased, in the "Cloud" view.  I clicked on one of the books, it downloaded, and I got into the full-screen reading mode.  If I move my mouse pointer to be in the left side of the screen, I can see a "left" icon appear to change the page; and similarly for the right side of the screen.  I can select text to create highlights, etc.

However, I can't figure out how to return to the main screen / library view that I initially saw when I launched the app.  How to return to that screen?  It isn't obvious or discoverable!  I've tried moving my mouse around and clicking in random places on the screen, to no avail – though I did discover the text highlighting capability.

So, to get back to the library view, where should I place my mouse pointer, and where should I click?  Is there a gesture I need to do?  Do I need to use the keyboard?  Is there a manual or online help for the Kindle app for Windows 8?  Feeling like a fish out of water with this modern UI app ;-)  Thanks.

Comment: If you used the appliation on Windows 7 you would do the exat samething.  The Kindle app from what I know is a normal desktop application at this point.

Comment: Try right-clicking. In Windows 8, a lot of options/actions are in the menus that show up when you right-click.

Comment: @Ramhound No, it isn't a desktop app. I'm referring to the Modern UI Kindle app that I just downloaded from the Windows 8 Store.

Comment: @nhinkle Thanks! The right mouse button did bring up a top and bottom menu.  Can you please post that as an answer so I can mark it accordingly?

Comment: Sure thing. I was hesitant to put it as an answer since I couldn't check myself :P

Comment: I just double-checked by installing the Kindle app, and it does look like that does the trick. Added a screenshot, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Modern UI apps, there are often important actions and options in menus on the top and bottom of the screen that only show up when you right-click. One of those options lets you go back to your library.

If you have a touchscreen or a touchpad, swiping in from the top will also reveal these menus.

[image: kindle swipe down screenshot]

Comment: FWIW, I had tried the gesture mentioned, but with *my mouse* .. so I needed a touchpad or touchscreen, eh? ;-)  Right-click did the trick though.  Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea right. The gesture only works on a touch device, otherwise you have to do the right-click. So for you you'll have to use the mouse to click, but I wanted to have the info be comprehensive in case anyone else came searching.

Answer (score 2):

Right click and choose "library" in the commands menu that pops down and up at top and bottom of sceen.

On a touch device and modern touchpad you should be able to swipe from top to activate the same menu, or you can press <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> with a keyboard.

Comment: +1 for the Win+Z keyboard shortcut.  That had the same effect as the right-click.